# convert an xs:float value to a hex-string representation of its binary value

Tags: xml, xslt, text

Using xsl 2.0, how would you convert an xs:float value to a hex-string representation of its binary value?  i have no problem doing this for an integer (divide by 16 recursively and concatenate chars 0-9A-F), but float/double is stumping me.

```
<xsl:function name="my:float-to-hex" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:float"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="magic-here($in)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

A valid answer may be that "this is not possible" and that would be valuable to me if it were true. I am open to other suggestions, but please don't depart from XSL. I am fully aware that there are more than one ways to skin this cat.

To clarify, the expected output would be the same as the output from this C code:

```
float f = 28.25f;
char *ptr = &f;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++) { printf("%02X", *(ptr + i)); }
```

#### third party edit

- see [XLS](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/)
- or [XLST 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/)

Comment: To be clear, your expected output for "28.25" would be "1C.4", correct?

Comment: the expected output cannot have the decimal point.  so for 28.25, the expected output would be 0000e241

Comment: So essentially you're trying to cast a value in XSLT

Comment: basically, i'm trying to output a binary format by creating intermediate hex-text that is trivial to convert into binary.

Comment: Purely out of interest - What's wrong with representing "28.25" as "28.25"? It's not that this is ambiguous or inaccurate or something, so what's the point of converting it to "0000E241"?

Comment: i have been tasked to convert xml data to an old data format, which is binary.

Comment: I see. Python, for example, has the ability to make user-defined functions available to XSLT (though it does not support XSLT 2.0, IIRC). I think you can find a way to do that part of your transformation outside of XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go out on a limb and say that this is impossible in vanilla XSLT. With access to user-definable extension functions it is easy to offshore it to some language better suited, as you already indicated yourself by `magic-here($in)`.

I don't think XSLT has a way to cast a number into a byte array. I can't point out a relevant section in the spec to prove it, though. Maybe someone else digs up the right paragraph.

XSLT is supposed to be deterministic and side-effects free, and as such it is highly unlikely that it provides a native way to access implementation specific details like the internal number representation.

Comment: i suspect that you are right.  in fact, i had already come close to the same conclusion myself, but i wanted a second opinion.  i've done quite a bit of reading on xslt and on the surface it is billed as capable of converting from xml to xml, xml to anything, and anything to xml; the latter two being more difficult, but possible.  however, i discovered that "to anything" should really be "to text" and the level of difficulty of going from "anything to xml" is very high.  Realizing that Saxon is pretty much the only XSL 2.0 tool available and the licensing is limited, I'm not impressed.

Comment: XSLT is an XML transformation language. Hence the name. It does not do low-level bit twiddling because that's not in the scope of the language. Binary representations of things are different in different environments, yielding the possibility of unpredictable/non-deterministic results. XSLT is turing-complete (even 1.0), but if it is painful to do a specific thing in XSLT, then chances are that it is just not the right tool for that job. And yes "anything" only means "text, formatted to your liking".